# How do I remove the scrollbar and display a solid border?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a page with a border wrapped around like this:
[image]

My html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stuff</title>
    <link href="css/projects.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```

But for some reason the page overflows at the bottom with a scrollbar and the bottom border gets cut off from the view until you scroll down. How do I make the border visible around the page without the scrollbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this:

```css
html {
        height: 100%;
        border: 10px solid red;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stuff</title>
    <link href="css/projects.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

`box-sizing: border-box` does exactly what you want, that is, to make the border not count towards the height of the element. It will take space inside the element instead of outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the 100% height is taken into consideration **before** the additional border height is calculated. To avoid the overflow, you need to subtract the `20px` (10px on the top and bottom) from the 100% height calculation. This can be done with `calc(100% - 20px)`:

```css
html {
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stuff</title>
    <link href="css/projects.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps! :)